# What is a Polyhedral Set?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

Is the following set a Polyhedral ?

$S = \{x \in \mathbb R^2 : |x_1|+ |x_1| \leq 1 \}$

Can anyone please tell me what is the exact meaning of Polyhedral set ?

I was given to check if this set is Polyhedral or not. I do not know the term Polyhedral. But I know Polyhedron.

I have not got he meaning of the term 'Polyhedral'  in the internet as well.

Comment: Please provide context: why are you interested in this? What's the definition of "polyhedral set" you are referring to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A polyhedral set is a set which can be expressed as the intersection of a finite set of closed half-spaces, i.e., as $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : Ax \leq b\}$ for some matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ and vector $b\in\mathbb{R}^m$.

Your set is polyhedral, take
$$A = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1 \\ -1 & 1 \\ -1 & -1\end{pmatrix} \quad \text{and} \quad b = \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: So $\mathbb R^2 - S$  will not be  a polyhedral set@LinAlg

Comment: @sani if you mean $\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x \not\in S\}$, not the Minkowski difference, then yes, that set is not polyhedral. Polyhedral sets are necessarily convex.